# JAX-WS and JAX-RPC Client Fault Handling

Tags: java, web-services, exception, jax-ws, jax-rpc

I have a WSDL that was originally designed for JAX-RPC use. When I generate the client classes in JAX-RPC the exception it throws are correct and as per specifications. But when I use the same wsdl and generate the JAX-WS classes the exception class are very different. Now at this time when I call the service from JAX-WS I am not able to catch the correct exceptions.

Has some one faced a similar issue?
JAX-WS Class

```
public PaymentReference create(
    @WebParam(name = "cardCreateInfo", targetNamespace = "http://schema.XXX.com/2009/11/member/paymentInformation")
    CardCreateInfo cardCreateInfo)
    throws IfFaultMsg, IfSvcFaultMsg, InvalidCardHolderNameFaultMsg, InvalidExpirationDayFaultMsg, InvalidExpirationMonthFaultMsg, InvalidExpirationYearFaultMsg, InvalidPrimaryAccountNumberFaultMsg, InvalidTargetNameSpaceFaultMsg, PaymentInformationFaultMsg, PotentialDuplicateFoundFaultMsg, UnauthorizedApplicationFaultMsg
;
```

JAX-RPC Class

```
public com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.spiborIntegration.models.paymentInformation.PaymentReference create(com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.spiborIntegration.models.paymentInformation.CardCreateInfo cardCreateInfo) throws java.rmi.RemoteException, com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.spiborIntegration.models.paymentInformation.InvalidCardHolderNameException, com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.spiborIntegration.models.exception.IFException, com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.spiborIntegration.models.paymentInformation.UnauthorizedApplicationException, com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.spiborIntegration.models.paymentInformation.InvalidPrimaryAccountNumberException, com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.spiborIntegration.models.paymentInformation.InvalidExpirationMonthException, com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.spiborIntegration.models.paymentInformation.InvalidExpirationDayException, com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.spiborIntegration.models.paymentInformation.PaymentInformationException, com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.spiborIntegration.models.paymentInformation.PotentialDuplicateFoundException, com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.spiborIntegration.models.paymentInformation.InvalidExpirationYearException, com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.spiborIntegration.models.paymentInformation.InvalidTargetNameSpaceException, com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.spiborIntegration.models.exception.IFSvcException;
```

Is there a way to make sure the JAX-WS follows the pattern from JAX-RPC? Or if there is a way to catch the exception thrown as per JAX-RPC in the JAX-WS client classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an external binding file as described in [WSDL Customization](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.1.2/docs/customizations.html) to customise the mapping of WSDL faults to exception names.

This is described explicitly in [The Exception Class](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.1.2/docs/customizations.html#2.6.2_Exception_class).